# Activity tags not available in Drupal views Drupal 10.x, CiviCRM 5.66

Tags: drupal-views, civicrm-entity

Don't know if I'm being thick or if this is a bug. Creating an Activities view in Drupal and looking for Activity tag relationship to bring in activity tags to the display and they only show for Contacts. Am I missing something?